# Test NG test in eclipse fails with the error NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, testng

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1012)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.forName(ClassHelper.java:96)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:78)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:544)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1344)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:103)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
```

The stack trace of the exception is shown above

The test class is part of a project that makes use of maven for compilation and dependency management. I see that the 'Referenced Library' section in Eclipse contains all dependencies for the project. The classpath entry contains spring dependencies. Yet, I see this error while running the test class using Eclipse's test ng plugin. Please help me fix this exception! I am having a rough time fixing test ng issues in Eclipse :-(

Solutions that I have already tried and found not to be working -

1. Clean/Build project.
2. Uninstall/Reinstall testng eclipse plugin
3. Restart eclipse.

I don't think figuring out the jar that the class mentioned in exception and adding the jar to classpath is the right way to fix this issue since the project that the test class is part of already has all the dependencies in place.

How do I make sure the test environment has access to all the required jars?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this to pom.xml `<dependencies>` section and recompile your project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

scope tag means it wont be compiled into the final jar/war whatever you make.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when i was executing new TESTNG project for very first time. 
Solution: Its a minor thing when you create a new test NG project make sure you have added all the referenced libraries and TESTNG libriaries as well. Adding the libraries Guava 23.6 solved my issue.
Do try it if you as well have performed this silly mistake.